# Hide the html contorl from the server side without using attributes runat="Server"

Tags: asp.net

I am using HTML control,and want to visible false from the server side with out using attributes runat="Server"

tell me any solution

Comment: If you dont have `runat=server`, you dont have a serverside control anymore.

Comment: If I understand correctly he's just wanting to hide the control on the browser, misunderstanding what runat="server" actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Runat="Server" has got nothing to do with visibility.

If you want to hide the control (so that its not visible to any visitors to your site) you would simply set its CSS to `visibility:hidden;` or `display: none;`.  I think this is what you wanted to know.

Comment: As a clarification: Just adding css will still render the HTML, so it's still there for the customer. Implementing it as ScottE suggests will make it completely invisible for the browser (but I'm pretty sure you knew that).

Comment: Correct, but without using runat="Server" this is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your html controls in an asp:placeholder control, and set the visibility on the placeholder.

Example

```
<asp:placeholder id="plc" runat="server" visible="false">
    <h1>Some Content</h1>
    <img src="/images/someimage.gif" alt="" />
</asp:placeholder>
```

Comment: Doesn't he specify it won't be runat="server"?  That was my understanding.

Comment: He specifies a control, but not necessarily a container.